# Query multiple tables with LINQ, grab results to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have this simple SQL:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
AND t1.id = 123
```

How do I convert it to LINQ in C#, so that the results are in Dictionary?

Comment: Assuming that id is the primary key. If the id is 123, and you take the item from table t1 with id == 123 and the item from table t2 with id == 123, then you will only have one item. What is the purpose of putting this in a Dictionary? Please edit the question, such that we know the relevant parts of t1 and t2 (which one has Name, which one has Value), how do you access the data: entity framework? plain old DbCommand and DbReader? And write in words your requirements. Without them we just have to guess what you want, and apparently your current description is not specific enough.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you are using Entity Framework?
Could you use [RelationShips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) instead?

Or like this:

```
var query = from t1 in context.Table1
            from t2 in context.Table2
            where t1.Id == t2.Id
            select new { t1.name, t2.value};

var result = query.ToList();
var dir = result.ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators

Comment: Why `ToList` what purpose does it serve, you can pass the enumerable straight to `ToDictionary`

Comment: I wasn't sure what happens to the LINQ to SQL translator when you add ToDictionary, because it does not translate into ToDictionary. Maybe you are right :)